# Setting Checkbox selection limit(allow to select only 2)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually i am looking to set the limitation for checkbox selection. With the below Script i am copying column(1) of each row which is checked to the div(Summary).

**Javascrpit**

```
<script>
     var tableControl = document.getElementById('order-table');
     $('#jqcc').click(function () 
     {
     var result = []               
     var count = 
     document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
     var limit = 2;

        $('input:checkbox:checked', tableControl).each(function () {                
            result.push($(this).parent().next().text() + "," + "<br>");                                       
        });

    $("#Summary").html(result).show();

   });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
            <div class="form-group" id="jqcc">
            <table id="order-table" name="order-table">
               <tr>
                   <th>Select</th>
                   <th>Medication</th>
                   <th>Max Issue Limit</th>
                   <th>Quantity</th>
                   <th>X</th>
                   <th>Unit Price</th>
                   <th>=</th>
                   <th>Totals</th>
               </tr>
               <tbody id="contacts">
                    <tr class='odd'>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' class='single-checkbox'></td>
                    <td class='product-title'>" + item.Name + "</td>
                    <td>" + item.MaxIssueLimit + "</td>
                    <td class='hours'><input type='text' class='hours' oninput='calculate()'></input></td>
                    <td class='times'>X</td>
                    <td class='rate'><input type='text' class='rate' value=" + item.UnitPrice + " oninput='calculate()' disabled='disabled'/></td>
                    <td class='equals'>=</td>
                    <td class='date-total'><input type='text' class='date-total'  disabled='disabled'/></td>
                    <td class='med' style='display:none'>" + item.MedicationID + "</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class='odd'>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' class='single-checkbox'></td>
                    <td class='product-title'>" + item.Name1 + "</td>
                    <td>" + item.MaxIssueLimit1 + "</td>
                    <td class='hours'><input type='text' class='hours' oninput='calculate()'></input></td>
                    <td class='times'>X</td>
                    <td class='rate'><input type='text' class='rate' value=" + item.UnitPrice + " oninput='calculate()' disabled='disabled'/></td>
                    <td class='equals'>=</td>
                    <td class='date-total'><input type='text' class='date-total'  disabled='disabled'/></td>
                    <td class='med' style='display:none'>" + item.MedicationID + "</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class='odd'>
                    <td><input type='checkbox' class='single-checkbox'></td>
                    <td class='product-title'>" + item.Name2 + "</td>
                    <td>" + item.MaxIssueLimit2 + "</td>
                    <td class='hours'><input type='text' class='hours' oninput='calculate()'></input></td>
                    <td class='times'>X</td>
                    <td class='rate'><input type='text' class='rate' value=" + item.UnitPrice + " oninput='calculate()' disabled='disabled'/></td>
                    <td class='equals'>=</td>
                    <td class='date-total'><input type='text' class='date-total'  disabled='disabled'/></td>
                    <td class='med' style='display:none'>" + item.MedicationID + "</td>
                    </tr>              
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="portlet light bordered">
            <div class="portlet-title">
                <div class="caption">
                    <span class="caption-subject font-blue bold uppercase">
                        Summary
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>                              
            <div id="Summary" style="font-size:medium;">                   
            </div>
            <br>                
          </div>
          </div>
```

Now,i want to set the checkbox selection limitation. So, when i try to set the limit using if condition. i can able to set the limit, but when i try to click more than the limit, the copied contents of Div(Summary) also disable.

So, how can i set the limit without losing the copied contents from div(Summary)?

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: add some html to it. Turn it into a snippet if can

Comment: Added html part of the table and summary div @A.Lau

Comment: Your html is different to your javascript... you have `$('#divid').click` but there's no element with id `divid` in your example

Comment: Sorry, its #jqcc. I amended

Comment: maybe expand your `tbody` too, kind of hard to test your problem if you only have a single checkbox. maybe put five checkboxes in there or something, just more than 2.

Comment: What `limit` are we talking about here? Is it limit of allowed checks in the entire column?

Comment: Let's say. A table got 10 rows, each row got checkbox. So i need to set the user should allow to select only 2 rows. @Malky.Kid

Comment: i expanded the '<tbody>' already @A.Lau

Comment: Please try my answer out. Also edit the question to include that you want two checks only, and upvote and accept answers tha thave helped you :)

Comment: @Muzz I mean that you should add more `<tr>` into `<tbody>`. How do you expect me to test your checkboxes if I've only got 1 to check in there? Add some more.

Comment: Updated @A.Lau. Sorry for misunderstood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are many ways you can go about this

Simplest, I think, is to have a `var` that's available to all of your javascript functions that simply counts that's sole role is to count the number of checks user has already made.

Do this check them whenever a `Class` of the checkbox is `change(d)`

For example:

on an html that looks like this:

```
        <input type="checkbox" id='cb1' class='chkGroup'> Check1
        <input type="checkbox" id='cb2' class='chkGroup'> Check2
```

You can check with jquery like this

```
        var totChecks = 0;
        $('.chkGroup').on('change', function() {
              if($(this).prop("checked") == true)
              {
                 if(totChecks > 2){
                   /*cancel your action*/
                   console.log("too many checks!");
                   return false;
                 }
                 /*otherwise, proceed*/
                 totChecks = totChecks + 1;
              }
             else //checkbox is unchecked, so remove a point from totChecks.
              {
                totChecks = totChecks - 1;
              }
        });
```